# Ошибка System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора."

Tags: c#, oledb

Access 2016, VS 2017, C#

Ошибка System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора."
Ругается на OleDbDataReader tarif = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Нужно вывести запросом сумму выручки за определенный период, на форме 2 datetimepicker, textbox и button
Прошу помочь.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form13 : Form
    {
        public Form13()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form13_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 form3 = new Form3();
            this.Visible = false;
            form3.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Museum.mdb";
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(str);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select sum(Сумма) as Итого from Экскурсии where [Дата] between '"+ DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker1.Value)) + "' and  '"+ DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker1.Value)) + "'" , cn);
            cn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader tarif = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (tarif.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(tarif["Итого"]);
            }
            textBox1.TabStop = false;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете что-то странное датами при построении запроса. Сначала, вы их приводите к форматированной строке `string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker1.Value)` Т.е из типа DateTime получаете объект string. Далее вы обратно преобразуете строку в тип DateTime `DateTime.Parse(...` Т.е вы делаете два преобразования, которые на выходе не дают изменений. Ну и наконец, полученный DateTime вы конкатенируете со строками запроса. При конкатенации DateTime в очередной раз преобразуется в строку, но уже не по тому формату, который вы задали, а по тому который стоит в региональных настройках ОС, вернее в соответствии с так называемой *"текущей локалью"*.

Более того, при работе с датами в Access-диалекте SQL, литерал даты оформляется всё равно не просто как yyyy-MM-dd

Но от этих тонкостей с оформлении даты в строку лучше вообще абстрагироваться с помощью параметров.

```
...
var cn = new OleDbConnection(str);
string cmdtext = "Select sum(Сумма) as Итого " + 
                 "from Экскурсии " + 
                 "where [Дата] between ? and ?";
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdtext, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DT1", dateTimePicker1.Value));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DT2", dateTimePicker2.Value));
cn.Open();
OleDbDataReader tarif = cmd.ExecuteReader();
...
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что проблема в запросе, который ты пуляаешь, а именно в `WHERE`.

Я такое ловил в Access, если в сравниваемых полях мог быть NULL.
Так же, такая ошибка может вылетать из-за действиетлнього не соответствия типов= > нужно все привести к единообразному типу.